# Do "forgiven" felonies still count towards the ending?

Tags: disgaea-2

According to the explanation of Felonies on the [Disgaea wiki](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Felony) your felonies are forgiven when you reincarnate, although the benefits will remain in effect.

It also states that the number of Felonies that Adell has accumulated will affect the ending. Does reincarnation reset that count as well, or is it tallied separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a few posts in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/930240-disgaea-2-cursed-memories/49833279), paying double the usual Mana cost to "Reincarnate to Atone" will remove the effects of felonies on the ending:

> And as long as you reincarnate to atone for sins before you finish the game, you can still get the good ending. A special reincarnation erases those felonies for double mana cost: you lose the boost in assembly and discount at the shop, but keep the EXP multiplier.
>
> You can get all the felonies you want on them. As long as you do the special reincarnation before you beat the game, then you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know. Time for a few crime sprees.